# extract parameters from BashOperator in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I have the following operator:

```
import = BashOperator(
    task_id='import',
    bash_command="""python3 script.py `{{ var.value.run_value }}`  'file.json'""",
    dag=dag)
```

When I look on Rendered Template I see:

```
python3 script.py `2018-09-13 11:53:38.725089`  'file.json'
```

So far great.
However my script doesn't seem to work with this input:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if str(sys.argv[1]):
        time_value = str(sys.argv[1])[:-7]  # from 2018-09-13 11:01:18.287705 to 2018-09-13 11:01:18
    else:
        time_value = '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
    requestedDate = time_value.split(' ', 1)[0]          #From 2018-08-20 15:00:00  get only 2018-08-20
    requestedTime = (time_value.split(' ', 1)[1])[:-3]   #From 2018-08-20 15:00:00  get only 15:00
    pathConfigFile = (sys.argv[2])
```

This doesn't work.

What I want is:

```
time_value  =  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
requestedDate = YYYY-MM-DD
requestedTime = HH:MM:SS
pathConfigFile = 2nd parameter given.
```

Airflow shows me:

```
 {bash_operator.py:101} INFO - SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also, I can't even print the input.
When I try the code without Airflow as pure python script I don't have any issues.

I should note. Airflow is running under `Python 2.7` but the script is executing under `Python 3`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have quoted the macro in back-ticks, which Bash interprets as wanting to execute the contents. You should switch to single quotes.

Your rendered output should look like:

```
python3 script.py '2018-09-13 11:53:38.725089'  'file.json'
```